# Can you send text and file for the same param?

Tags: php, laravel, postman

I am trying to send a request to my PHP Laravel API that would store as “content” both files and text, however when i send the POST request, only the file path gets saved in the database and the request returns an array that is empty, is the problem from postman or my API?

[image]
[image]

Here is the code for my post:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'content' => 'required|max:255',
        'user_id' => 'required|exists:users,id',
        'item_id' => 'required|exists:items,id'
        ]);
    return Comment::create($request->all());
}
```

Comment: I would like to thank the people who helped me by editing the question to better suit the community's standards.

Comment: What type is `content`, is that of file type? Solve one thing at a time. Don't store it in DB until you don't know what exactly you have in request data. See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#files) how to check if file is there.

Comment: I wish for content to be a text that contains the image as well as the normal text, so it is of type text

Comment: Check JS `btoa` or similar function of how to convert binary to base-64 encoded string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try With change content to **content[file]**
and **content[text]**

this is work for me

Comment: but if I use x-www-form-urlencoded i cannot upload a file anymore

Comment: so stay in form-data and try with change content[file] ... @JadSamadi

Comment: just tried that and got Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\\Database\\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in, might be something to do with the request? But the database accepts text how can I tell it to accept an array? I dont think that is the logical/right approach anyway, perhaps I am misusing your answer?

Comment: in laravel validation you can set "content" => "array|required" @JadSamadi

Comment: I just tried that, and when i printed out the result i got {
    "text": "hello there how are you?",
    "file": {}
} however this is just how laravel is receiving the request content, when it comes to inserting in the database it is still giving the same error

Comment: how u want store file ? @JadSamadi

Comment: what i am hoping for is to save the request as a string, where it will contain for example "text" <file source> "text" in the database basically, close to what you get inside a wysiwyg editors

Comment: I recommend to you use $request->file->store("your path") and save the path and file name to your DB  @JadSamadi

Comment: I am a already doing that in another stage in the code, my problem is not with uploading the file, but connecting the file to the database, every entry in the database can have multiple files as well as text (just as any forums chat/editor) and even though I did considering simply linking them up I did not figure out how to efficiently link them up and display them such as the user has sent them thus came my question inside my post, maybe try an approach of sending an html form containing all the info and img tag but I am still thinking of it as an approach